# Add delay in Twilio statuscallback

Tags: twilio

Is there any method through which I could add a time delay to get SMS StatusCallBack URL response from Twilio?
OR
Is there any other way through which I can let Twilio know that my service to process you callBack response is unavailable now?

Example: if I sent an SMS through Twilio with a StatusCallBack, I would be able to get after 1 minute of time delay in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way to delay the SMS statusCallBack. If you are unable to deal with a statusCallBack when it is sent, you could poll the API to check the current status of an SMS message.

Can I ask why you wouldn't make your service available to receive callbacks at any time?

Comment: I want to implement two different solutions in my project,
**1. Process the response from the callback.**
**2. Poll the API to check the status of my message.**

After I'm sending messages I insert the messageSId in a table to process it later and I want to get the response from the callback and update it's status on the table. Before I insert a record in a table I got the response from Twilio and that messageSId isn't found the table so no record is updated. The delay in callback response and the insertion is an approx **10-15 sec**.

Comment: In that case, if you can't find that you've already entered the messageSid in the table, then you could use the response from the callback to populate the row instead as the callback will include all the standard parameters about a message, as well as the `MessageStatus` and `ErrorCode` (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional).

Comment: Thanks.
I'll check if there isn't any messageSId present in the table then we insert the result of callback.

Comment: Excellent! Let me know if you need any more help. Do please mark the answer as solved if this has sorted your problem too. Thanks

Comment: I've implement 2 approaches in my project, 1. get the records from Twilio logs and 2. Process the status callback response from Twilio.
The issue which I was facing is done by making the messageSId as unique identifier and due to unique identity it won't allow me to add duplicate row. When I got the exception I retry to update the record which is already inserted.